# Go back to } in vim - equivalent of [} or ]{

Tags: vim

In vim I can hit `[{` to go back to the first unmatched `{` or `]}` to go forward likewise. Is there something (short) that acts like `[}` so I can go back to the last `}`?

Comment: `?}<Enter>` is a dumb, but still fairly fast, version.

Comment: On the same line `F}` but obviously you'd want to go over lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a built in command to do what you want.  I think it'd be easiest to add a simple mapping like

```
map <Leader>} ?}<Cr>
```

to let you hit leader} (leader is \ if you haven't remapped it) and go back to the most recent }.